# Could not write to file pom.xml android

Tags: android, maven

Unable to push android library to maven. It is giving following error. 
**"Could not edit /../../pom.xml file"....
caused by InvalidUserDataException: The configuration to scope mapping is not unique**. Please help.

Comment: Same thing here w/ latest macOS Android Studio 2.3.2 & SDK updates (also tried on 3.0 canary and get the same problem) when I "gradlew uploadArchives". I haven't run a build in nearly a month, but this last worked fine on May 15 2017 w/ little to no changes in *MY* code.

Comment: I reverted from com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2 to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1 and the problem went away. :/ If this works for you, since you are new here I will let you answer it and i'll upvote it to give you some more rep.

Comment: 2.3.3 was released today that also appears to work

Comment: Important correction! I changed two things when I got my build working. One was reverting the previously mentioned android gradle version, the other was to revert from MultiDexApplication back to a basic Application. I went back to 2.3.2 and could not repro the problem. I went back to MultiDexApplication on 2.3.1 and 2.3.2 and could repro the problem. So, it looks like this is a MultiDexApplication problem. Are you using MultiDexApplication?

Comment: @swooby you saved my life!! I disabled multiDex and the problem went away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with version and scope mapping while updating your pom file.If multiple mappings are found for same dependencies exception is thrown. 
[You can see it here for unique property mapping in spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9d6c38bd54fe8931ee73fbb7a076625deb934e28/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/springframework/build/gradle/MergePlugin.groovy#L136). 
For Android, you must use an updated version of standard maven plugin [Android Maven Plugin](https://github.com/strongloop-forks/android-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/AndroidMavenPlugin.java).

This might help you [Repository link and integration details.](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the `InvalidUserDataException` by using as of today the latest version of the *multidex* library: [`androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/multidex#2.0.1).
I verified that the error occurs when I use `androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0`.
I also verified that the error does **not** occur when I keep using `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3` in combination with `android.enableJetifier=true`.